# get Jwplayer or flowplayer to play video from CDN for php melody script

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, jwplayer, cdn, jwplayer6

I'm adding a CDN to a video sharing website, having some problems Configuring a CDN customer origin server.
I have created a pull zone and adding a Cname record.
My CDN Provider send me a message :
I've tested your website and noticed that videos are not loaded from the CDN yet
but the file is loaded from http://www.xxxxxx.com/uploads/videos/ce404c67.mp4
What we recommend you to configure your website to listen to an additional hostname
for example origin.avimeo.com and configure this host as origin for your CDN zone.
After this is created, you have to change the links in your video player to the CNAME
that you configured in your CDN zone. This way the video player will request the content
from our CDN and our CDN will serve the movie (after it loaded it form the origin host).
How can i change the links in your video player to the CNAME.
This is player.tpl template for players :

Jwplayer :

{if $video_data.video_player == "jwplayer6"}

```
    {literal}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{/literal}{$smarty.const._URL2}{literal}/players/jwplayer6/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="{/literal}{$jwplayerkey}{literal}";</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {
                {/literal}
                    {if $video_data.source_id == 0 || $video_data.source_id == 0}
                        file: '{$video_data.jw_flashvars.file}',
                        streamer: '{$video_data.jw_flashvars.streamer}',
                        {literal}rtmp: {{/literal}
                        {if $video_data.jw_flashvars.provider != ''} provider: '{$video_data.jw_flashvars.provider}',
                        {/if}
                        {if $video_data.jw_flashvars.startparam != ''} startparam: '{$video_data.jw_flashvars.startparam}',
                        {/if}
                        {if $video_data.jw_flashvars.loadbalance != ''} loadbalance: {$video_data.jw_flashvars.loadbalance},
                        {/if}
                        {if $video_data.jw_flashvars.subscribe != ''} subscribe: {$video_data.jw_flashvars.subscribe},
                        {/if}
            {if $video_data.jw_flashvars.securetoken != ''} securetoken: "{$video_data.jw_flashvars.securetoken}",
                        {/if}
                        },
                    {elseif $video_data.source_id == 3}
                        {literal}
                        file: '{/literal}{$video_data.direct}{literal}',
                        {/literal}
                    {elseif $video_data.source_id == 1}
                        {literal}
                        file: '{/literal}{$video_data.url_flv}{literal}',
                        {/literal}
                    {else}      
                        {literal}
                        file: '{/literal}{$video_data.url_flv}{literal}',
                        {/literal}
                    {/if}
                    {literal}
                    flashplayer: "{/literal}{$smarty.const._URL2}{literal}/players/jwplayer6/jwplayer.flash.swf",                        
                    primary: "flash",
                    width: "100%",
                    {/literal}{if $playlist}{literal}
                    height: "401",
                    autostart: true, 
                    {/literal}{else}{literal}
                    height: "{/literal}{$smarty.const._PLAYER_H}{literal}",
                    autostart: "{/literal}{$smarty.const._AUTOPLAY}{literal}", 
                    {/literal}{/if}{literal}
                    image: '{/literal}{$video_data.preview_image}{literal}',
                    stretching: "fill",
                    events: {
                        {/literal}{if $playlist}{literal}
                        onComplete: function() {
                            window.location = "{/literal}{$playlist_next_url}{literal}";
                        },
                        {/literal}{/if}{literal}
                        onError: function(object) { 
                            ajax_request("video", "do=report&vid={/literal}{$video_data.uniq_id}{literal}&error-message="+ object.message, "", "", false);
                            {/literal}{if $playlist}{literal}
                            window.location = "{/literal}{$playlist_next_url}{literal}";
                            {/literal}{/if}{literal}
                        }
                    },
                    logo: {
                        file: '{/literal}{$smarty.const._WATERMARKURL}{literal}',
                        link: '{/literal}{$smarty.const._WATERMARKLINK}{literal}',
                    }
                    };
                    {/literal}{$jw_flashvars_override}{literal}
        jwplayer("Playerholder").setup(flashvars);
    </script>
    {/literal}
```

PHP SOURCE : 
Do you mean this part :

```
$video_sources = fetch_video_sources();
$video_src_name = '';

$temp       = array();
$video      = array();
$mime_type  = 'video/x-flv';

$video_id   = secure_sql($_GET['vid']);

$sql = "SELECT pm_videos.*, pm_videos_urls.mp4, pm_videos_urls.direct 
        FROM pm_videos 
        LEFT JOIN pm_videos_urls 
               ON (pm_videos.uniq_id = pm_videos_urls.uniq_id) 
        WHERE pm_videos.uniq_id = '". $video_id ."'";

$result =  @mysql_query($sql);
$video = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_free_result($result);

$mime_types = array('flv' => 'video/x-flv',
                    'mp4' => 'video/mp4',
                    'mov' => 'video/quicktime',
                    'wmv' => 'video/x-ms-wmv',
                    'divx' => 'video/divx',
                    'avi' => 'video/divx',
                    'mkv' => 'video/divx',
                    'asf' => 'video/x-ms-asf', 
                    'wma' => 'audio/x-ms-wma', 
                    'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg', 
                    'm4v' => 'video/mp4', 
                    'm4a' => 'audio/mp4', 
                    '3gp' => 'video/3gpp', 
                    '3g2' => 'video/3gpp2' 
                    );

define('PHPMELODY', true);

$divx_player = false;
if ($video['source_id'] == 1 || $video['source_id'] == 2)
{
    $tmp_parts = explode('.', $video['url_flv']);
    $ext = array_pop($tmp_parts);
    $ext = strtolower($ext);

    if ($ext == 'mkv' || $ext == 'avi' || $ext == 'mkv')
    {
        $divx_player = true;
    }
}

if ( ! $divx_player)
{
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $video['restricted'] == '1')
    {
        echo $lang['registration_req'];
        exit();
    }   
}

$video_src_name = strtolower($video_sources[$video['source_id']]['source_name']);

switch ($video_src_name)
{
    case 'youtube': // Youtube

        include(ABSPATH . _ADMIN_FOLDER ."/src/youtube.php");

        if ($video['direct'] == '')
        {
            $video['direct'] = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='. $video['yt_id'];
        }

        $flv_url = get_flv($video['direct'], _USE_HQ_VIDS);

    break;


    case 'dailymotion': // Dailymotion

        @include(ABSPATH . _ADMIN_FOLDER ."/src/dailymotion.php");

        if (_USE_HQ_VIDS)
        {
            $flv_url = get_hd($video['direct']);
        }
        if ((_USE_HQ_VIDS && ($flv_url == '' || strlen($flv_url) < 10)) || ( ! _USE_HQ_VIDS))
        {
            $flv_url = get_flv($video['direct']);
        }
    break;

    case 'veoh':    // VEOH

        @include(ABSPATH . _ADMIN_FOLDER ."/src/veoh.php");

        do_main($temp, $video['direct']);
        $flv_url = $temp['url_flv'];
        unset($temp);
    break;

    case 'metacafe': // Metacafe

        @include(ABSPATH . _ADMIN_FOLDER ."/src/metacafe.php");

        $flv_url = get_flv($video['direct']);
        unset($temp);
    break;

    case 'funnyordie': // FunnyOrDie

        $parts = explode("/", $video['direct']);
        $vid_id = $parts[ count($parts)-2 ];
        $flv_url = 'http://videos0.ordienetworks.com/videos/'.$vid_id.'/sd.flv';
    break;

    case 'vimeo': // Vimeo

        @include(ABSPATH . _ADMIN_FOLDER ."/src/vimeo.php");

        do_main($temp, $video['direct']);
        $flv_url = $temp['url_flv'];
        unset($temp);
    break;


    case 'google':  //  Google

        @include(ABSPATH . _ADMIN_FOLDER ."/src/google.php");

        do_main($temp, $video['direct']);

        $flv_url = $temp['url_flv'];
        unset($temp);
    break;

    case 'myspace': // Myspace

        @include(ABSPATH . _ADMIN_FOLDER ."/src/myspace.php");
        do_main($temp, $video['direct']);

        $flv_url = $temp['url_flv'];
        unset($temp);

        if ($flv_url == '')
        {
            report_video($video['uniq_id'], '1', 'The *.FLV URL was not found', 'PM Bot');
        }

    break;

    case 'break': //    break.com

        if (strpos($video['url_flv'], 'media1.break'))
        {
            $video['url_flv'] = str_replace('media1.', 'video1.', $video['url_flv']);

            $sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET url_flv = '". secure_sql($video['url_flv']) ."' 
                        WHERE id = '". $video['id'] ."'";
            @mysql_query($sql);
        }

        $flv_url = $video['url_flv'];

    break;

    case 'sevenload': // sevenload

        @include(ABSPATH . _ADMIN_FOLDER ."/src/sevenload.php");

        if ($video['direct'] == '')
        {
            $video['direct'] = 'http://en.sevenload.com/videos/'. $video['yt_id'] .'-';

            $headers = fetch_headers($video['direct']);
            $arr_length = count($headers);

            for($i = 0; $i < $arr_length; $i++)
            {
                if(strpos($headers[$i], "ocation:") !== false)
                {
                    $str1 = explode("ocation:", $headers[$i]);
                    $video['direct'] = trim($str1[1]);
                    break;
                }
            }

            @mysql_query("UPDATE pm_videos_urls SET direct='". $video['direct'] ."' WHERE uniq_id = '". $video['uniq_id'] ."'");
        }

        do_main($temp, $video['direct']);

        $flv_url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $temp['url_flv']);
        unset($temp);

    break;

    case 'trilulilu': // trilulilu.ro

        if (strlen($video['direct']) == 0)
        {
            if (strlen($video['url_flv']) > 0)
            {
                $flv_url = $video['url_flv'];
            }
            else
            {
                report_video($video['uniq_id'], '1', 'The *.FLV URL was not found', 'PM Bot');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            @include(ABSPATH . _ADMIN_FOLDER ."/src/trilulilu.php");
            do_main($temp, $video['direct']);
            $flv_url = $temp['url_flv'];
            unset($temp);   
        }           
    break;

    case 'vbox7':

        @include(ABSPATH . _ADMIN_FOLDER ."/src/vbox7.php");
        do_main($temp, $video['direct']);
        $flv_url = $temp['url_flv'];
        unset($temp);   

    break;

    case 'mynet':

        @include(ABSPATH . _ADMIN_FOLDER ."/src/mynet.php");

        do_main($temp, $video['direct']);

        $flv_url = $temp['url_flv'];
        $flv_url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $flv_url);
        unset($temp);

    break;

    default:

        if ($video['source_id'] == 1 || $video['source_id'] == 2)
        {
            if(strpos($video['url_flv'], 'http://') !== false || strpos($video['url_flv'], 'https://') !== false)
            {
                $flv_url = $video['url_flv'];
            }
            else
            {
                $flv_url = _VIDEOS_DIR . $video['url_flv'];
            }

            $tmp_parts = explode('.', $video['url_flv']);
            $ext = array_pop($tmp_parts);
            $ext = strtolower($ext);

            if (array_key_exists($ext, $mime_types))
            {
                $mime_type = $mime_types[$ext];
            }
            else if (function_exists('finfo_open')) 
            {
                $finfo      = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
                $mime_type  = finfo_file($finfo, _VIDEOS_DIR_PATH . $video['url_flv']);
                finfo_close($finfo);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $flv_url = $video['url_flv'];
        }

    break;
}

@update_view_count($video['id'], $video['site_views']);


header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Content-Type: ". $mime_type);
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header('Location: '. $flv_url);
```

}

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are running this?

Comment: where i'm running this ? can't understand exactly what you want

Comment: Do you mean this part :

Comment: He wants a link to your website.

Comment: Exactly...a link to your website.

Comment: http://www.avimeo.com/watch.php?vid=39a6fd0fe

Comment: cname : content.avimeo.com

Comment: Thia is playing fine. No issues here.